# Don't know how to print an entire Calendar at once

Tags: assembly, dos

```
cseg segment
assume cs:cseg, ds:cseg
org 100H
begin:   
                mov es,cs:[video]
                mov ax,3
                int 10h 
                mov cs:[col],0fh
                mov di,10               ;greeting msg will be printed after 10 spaces
                lea si,greeting
                call mess
                call nline        
                call jan
                call nline
                mov ah,4ch
                int 21h

col             db 0
greeting        db "Welcome to the 2015 Calendar ",0  
video           dw 0b800h
january         db  "         January$",     
string          db  "Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat$"
string1         db  "         1   2   3   4   5$"
string2         db  " 6   7   8   9  10  11  12$"
string3         db  "13  14  15  16  17  18  19$"
string4         db  "20  21  22  23  24  25  26$"
string5         db  "27  28  29  30  31$"

mess            proc
                push ax
                mov ah,cs:[col]
                mov bh, 30
conmess:
                mov al,cs:[si]
                or al,al
                jz endmess
                mov es:[di],ax  
                mov es:[di+1],bh
                inc si
                add di,2
                jmp conmess
endmess:
                pop ax
                ret
mess            endp

nline           proc
                mov ah, 2                    ; carriage return
                mov DL, 0DH
                int 21H    
                mov DL, 0AH                  ; line feed
                int 21H 
                ret
nline           endp   

print: 
                ;printing the line
                mov bh,10h  ;color attribute
                mov ah,9 
                mov al,0  ;avoding extra characters
                int 10h   ;printing color
                int 21h
                ret 

jan             proc 
                lea dx,january               ; load & display the STRIN
                call print
                call nline
                lea dx, string               ; load & display the STRING 
                call print
                call nline
                lea dx, string1              ; load & display the STRING 
                call print
                call nline
                lea DX, string2               ; load & display the STRING 
                call print
                call nline
                lea DX, string3               ; load & display the STRING 
                call print 
                call nline
                lea DX, string4               ; load & display the STRING 
                call print      
                call nline
                lea DX, string5               ; load & display the STRING 
                call print
                call nline 
                ret
jan             endp

cseg ends
end begin
```

Answer (score 3):

```
assume cs:cseg, ds:cseg
org 100H
```

Because you used `org 100h` I assume you are writing an executable in DOS'.COM format.

```
mov di,10               ;greeting msg will be printed after 10 spaces
```

To produce 10 spaces you need to setup DI=20 because in the video RAM at 0B800h every character occupies 2 bytes.

```
mess  proc
  push ax
  mov ah,cs:[col]
  mov bh, 30         ; You don't need this line
 conmess:
  mov al,cs:[si]
  or al,al
  jz endmess
  mov es:[di],ax  
  mov es:[di+1],bh   ; You don't need this line
  inc si
  add di,2
  jmp conmess
 endmess:
  pop ax
  ret
mess  endp
```

The greeting message is displayed by directly writing in the video RAM. Why did you insert 2 ways to define the attribute byte?

```
print:
 mov bh,10h  ; Delete this line
 mov ah,9 
 mov al,0    ; Delete this line
 int 10h     ; Delete this line
 int 21h
 ret
```

The rest of the writing is done via DOS functions. This *print* routine seems to mix BIOS and DOS functions!!! For DOS you only need AH=9

```
mov ah,4ch
int 21h
```

The Terminate function expects you to define an exit code in the AL register. Use `mov ax,4C00h`.

In stead of the cumbersome calling of *nline* to produce a CRLF you could easily write both these bytes in the string that you want to output.
Like this example

```
string2         db  " 6   7   8   9  10  11  12",13,10,"$"
```

Most of your routines are declared using PROC/ENDP but *print* is not. Please choose one system and stick to it.

EDIT

Since all of your strings are displayed on separate lines the easiest solution to give them color is to wipe the current line using the desired attribute. Here's how you do it for the first string

```
mov ax,0920h                    \
mov bx,001Eh  ;Yellow on Blue    | Best put this in a subroutine!
mov cx,80                        |
int 10h                         /
lea dx,january
call print
call nline
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But however there is one more thing i need to print it in color. Which i am having trouble with. Is there anyway to write all these strings in color highlighted format?

Comment: I added color to the output.

Comment: Thank you this codes works completely

Comment: @0ptimus : This is an old question and answer. Since  the answer solved your problem could you accept the answer please? Thanks.