# The codes below for printing calendar is working for texted mode. How can i make this calendar working in video mode?

Tags: assembly, tasm

```
.model small
.data

    instexit    db "Press any key to exit $"                      ;instant exit
    navb            db "Press B to end or N for Next Month: $"                        ;navigation instruction of january month
    nav             db "Press B for previous month or N for Next Month: $"            ;navigation instruction of months between january and december
    nave            db "Press B for previous month or N to end: $"                    ;navigation instruction of december month                                                               ; setting of value to zero
    greeting        db "Welcome to the 2015 Calendar$"                                ;greetings message displayed in the beginning

-------

    Jan             db  "         January$          "                                       ;whole january month
    string          db  "Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat$"                  ;prints the day string and the string will be used througout the months
    string1         db  "                 1   2   3$"
    string2         db  " 4   5   6   7   8   9  10$"
    string3         db  "11  12  13  14  15  16  17$"
    string4         db  "18  19  20  21  22  23  24$"
    string5         db  "25  26  27  28  29  30  31$"

; taking out the other strings for month due to the character limitation here

.code
.386            

        mov ax,@data
        mov ds,ax                                                                   
                mov ax,0003h                 ;setting screen to  80*25
                int 10h                
                mov ah,02h  
                mov bh,00   
                mov dh,1    
                mov dl,25
                int 10h               
                lea dx,greeting          ; load & display the STRING
                call print

                call nline               ;function for next line
                call january             ;prints whole january month
                mov cx,1                 ;counter for navigation

command:                    
                mov ah,1h                ;user input
                int 10h          ;        ;calling the interrupt handler

                cmp al,'n'               ;comparing which button user pressed 
                jz up            ;jumping to up function for cx addition with 1

                cmp al,'b'               ;comparing which button user pressed
                jz down      ;jumping to up function for cx subtraction with 1

ending:                
                mov ax,4C00h    
                int 21h
up:           
                inc cx                   ;added one to cx for watching the next month
                jmp navigate             ;jumping to display the desired calendar
down:               
                dec cx                   ;subtracting one to cx for watching the previous month
                jmp navigate             ;jumping to display the desired calendar

navigate:               
                cmp cx,1 
                jz m1             ;jumping to print january

  ; similar function has been taken due to space issues

                cmp cx,0     
                jz ending    ;end the program

                cmp cx,13     
                jz ending    ;end the program

m1:              
                call clr     ;clear out the screen
                call nline   ;prints the next line
                call january ;print the whole january month

jmp command

; similar month function has been taken due to space issues

clr:                              ;clears the screen
                mov ax,0003h
                int 10h 
                ret


nline:                       ;prints next line
                mov ah, 2                    ;carriage return
                mov dl, 0DH
                int 10h         ;    
                mov dl, 0AH                  ;line feed
                int 10h         ;
                ret


print:                                       ;prints the string 
                mov ah,9 
                int 10h     ;
                ret 


color1:                                      ;assigning the color for the string
                mov ax,0920h                    
                mov bx,0047h                 ;white on red   
                mov cx,30                       
                int 10h
                ret


color2:                                     ;assigning the color for the string
                mov ax,0920h                    
                mov bx,0021h                ;blue on green   
                mov cx,30                       
                int 10h
                ret


january:            ;prints the whole januarty month

                push cx

                mov ah,02h  
                mov bh,00   
                mov dh,2    
                mov dl,25
                int 10h

                call color1               
                lea dx,Jan                   ; load & display the STRING
                call print

                call nline                    ;prints the next line

                mov ah,02h  
                mov bh,00   
                mov dh,3    
                mov dl,25
                int 10h

                call color2
                lea dx, string               ; load & display the STRING 
                call print
                                             ;prints the next line

                call nline                   ;prints the next line

                mov ah,02h  
                mov bh,00   
                mov dh,4    
                mov dl,25
                int 10h

                call color2
                lea dx, string1              ; load & display the STRING 
                call print

                call nline                   ;prints the next line

                mov ah,02h  ;changing the rows and columns and bring it to center
                mov bh,00   
                mov dh,5                     ;shifting row
                mov dl,25                    ;shifting column
                int 10h

                call color2
                lea dx, string2               ; load & display the STRING 
                call print

                call nline                    ;prints the next line

                mov ah,02h  
                mov bh,00   
                mov dh,6    
                mov dl,25
                int 10h

                call color2
                lea dx, string3               ; load & display the STRING 
                call print 

                call nline                    ;prints the next line

                mov ah,02h  
                mov bh,00   
                mov dh,7    
                mov dl,25
                int 10h

                call color2
                lea dx, string4               ; load & display the STRING 
                call print      

                call nline                    ;prints the next line

                mov ah,02h  
                mov bh,00   
                mov dh,8    
                mov dl,25
                int 10h

                call color2
                lea dx, string5               ; load & display the STRING 
                call print

                call nline                    ;prints the next line
                call nline                    ;prints the next line
        lea dx,instexit           ;Instructions for instant exit
                call print
        call nline
                lea dx,navb
                call print
                pop cx           

                ret

; similar month functions has been taken due to space issues

end
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean when saying "making it work in video mode" ?

Comment: Are you running under DOS?

Comment: I am running tasm and I wrote these codes to print the whole calendar but my professor said that its in the text mode because I used it 21h. He don't want me to use this. I believe it is in the dos mode

Comment: Answer = http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29460318/how-to-print-colored-string-in-assembly-language/29478158#29478158

Answer (score 1):

```
command:                    
mov ah,1h                ;user input
int 10h          ;        ;calling the interrupt handler

nline:                       ;prints next line
mov ah, 2                    ;carriage return
mov dl, 0DH
int 10h         ;    
mov dl, 0AH                  ;line feed
int 10h         ;
ret

print:                                       ;prints the string 
mov ah,9 
int 10h     ;
ret
```

In the above code you have to change every occurence of `int 10h` into `int 21h`. Remember that you are using DOS functions.

To answer your question. Once this program works in **text** video mode then it will also work in **graphics** video mode. Certainly the legacy video modes, those with numbers from 1 to 19.

Comment: But with some other videomodes for a higher resolution maybe there is no support for a text output from the bios and we have to draw the text with an access to the framebuffer with colored pixel. For to switch into a videomode we can use the VESA-VBE-Bios. More details about the VBE-bios can be found inside the public and costfree document "vbe3.pdf" from vesa.org (need register/login).